# Sonarqube merge 2 components

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I have two SonarQube components that existed under the same directory.  Rather than running analysis of both sub-directories, I'd like to view only the parent.

I would prefer not to delete the issues and triage in SonarQube.  Is there a way to merge two components?

The directory structure of the code is 
component name="my-child-project" 
source-dir="parent-project/my-child-project"

component name="perm-module-c7000" 
source-dir="parent-project/my-other-child-project"

I would like to combine these into
component name="parent-project"
source-dir="parent-project"

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project perm-modules: The project 'com.chn.mgmt:my-child-project:3.00' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project 'com.chn.mgmt:parent-project:3.00'. If you really want to stop directly analysing project 'com.chn.mgmt:my-child-project:3.00', please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project 'com.chn.mgmt:parent-proejct:3.00'. -> [Help 1]